# Getting a "list index can't be a float" error when i use the same iterator from a loop in an if statment in Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I try to iterate through a list and check each value if it is a negative number, using the following code :

```
for i in listy:
    if (listy[i]<0):...
```

For some reason, python tries to evaluate `listy[0.5]<0`,  which is the 1st item on the list. How can I fix this ?

Comment: `i` is not the index, it's the *value*.

Comment: Please check python documentaion/tutorial to see how `for` works in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the value not the index.
This line is not what you want `(listy[i]<0)`.

You probably meant to do `i<0`

`(listy[i]<0)` is trying to use the value as the index. In you list the value is a float which can't be used as an index.

If you really want to use the index you could do:

```
for i in range(len(listy)):
    if listy[i] < 0:
        #do something
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! i've been banging my head for hours to fix this.
Moreover i was using "i" as an integer used in C and C++.

Comment: @Demis haha no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In C and many other languages, you often use the length of an array when iterating through it. You can do this in Python as well but you can also iterate through the elements without explicitly using the index (position). You seem to be mixing the two approaches and therefore you get an unexpected result.

This will iterate through the values only:

```
for i in listy:
    # here, i is the value of the list entry
    print(i)
```

This will use the length of the list and the index (position):

```
for i in range(len(listy)):
    # here, i is the index (position) of the list entry, not the value
    print(listy[i])
```

This will give you both index and value:

```
for i, val in enumerate(listy):
    # here, i is the index (position) and val is the value 
    print(i, val)
```